# Second Mean Value Theorem of Integral Proof

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

This is from [wikipedia on MVT.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem)

[image]

EDIT: Now that user Marsan has given a proof, why does the interval need not contain $a$? $H$ is continuous at $[a,b]$. What happens if $ \int G \phi \, dt = 0$?

---

Comment: Besides being monotone, ss long as $G$ is (bounded in $(a, b)$) then $a$ con be added to the domain of $g$ be setting $G(a)=\lim_{x\rightarrow a+}G(x)=G(a+)$. Same for $b$, $G(b):=\lim_{x\rightarrow b-}G(x)=G(b-)$. If $G$ is not bounded then things may fail.  There is a slightly more general result that extends to Lebesgue integration. I posted a solution in that setting below in case  that is still of interest to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First assume $G$ is a positive decreasing staircase function, say $G= \sum_{i=1}^n f_i \cdot \chi_{]x_{i-1}, x_i[}$, where $a= x_0 < x_1 < \cdots<x_n=b$, $f_i$ are positive real numbers and $\chi_{]x_{i-1}, x_i[}$ denotes the indicator function of the interval $]x_{i-1}, x_i [$. Let $H: x \in [a,b] \mapsto \int_a^x \phi $. The function H is (absolutely) continuous. By the intermediate value theorem it suffices to show that $$ m G(a^+) \leq \int_a^b G\phi \leq M G(a^+)$$ where $ m = \min H$ and $M = \max H$. Notice that $f_1 = G(a^+)$. Now, \begin{align}\int_a^b G\phi &= \sum_{i=1}^n \int_{x_{i-1}}^{x_{I}}f_i\phi \\ & = \sum_{i=1}^n f_i (H(x_{i}) - H(x_{i-1})) \\ & = \sum_{i=1}^n f_i H(x_i) - \sum_{i=1}^n f_i H(x_{i-1})\\ & = \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\underbrace{(f_i - f_{i+1})}_{\geq 0}H(x_i) + f_nH(b)\end{align} This yields $$ m\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(f_i -f_{i+1}) + f_n \right) \leq \int_a^b G\phi \leq M\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(f_i -f_{i+1}) + f_n \right) $$ and thus we get the inequality which was desired, which proves the result.

Now you can easily approximate $G$ as a limit of staircase positive decreasing functions to conclude.

Comment: User Marsan, I am confused why we do not need $a$ in the interval(? see edit).

Comment: well, you can always choose staircase functions that are zero at $a$. If you think about it, this is pretty obvious, because the integral of any measurable function (with respect to the measure $dx$) on an interval $[a,b]$ is equal to the integral of this function on $]a,b[$

Answer (score 3):

For a different approach, the function  $\varPhi: x \mapsto  \int_a^x \varphi(t) \, dt$ is continuous and since $G$ is monotone we have  that $\varPhi$ is Riemann-Stieltjes integrable with respect to $G$.  From integration by parts, it follows that $G$ is integrable with respect to $\varPhi$ and

$$\int_a^b G \, d\varPhi= G(b)\varPhi(b) - G(a)\varPhi(a) - \int_a^b \varPhi \, dG  = G(b)\varPhi(b) - \int_a^b \varPhi \, dG.$$

It also follows from a general property of the Riemann-Stieltjes integral that if $G$ and $\varphi$ are Riemann integrable, which is the case here, then

$$\int_a^bG(t) \varphi(t) \, dt = \int_a^b G \, d\varPhi = G(b)\varPhi(b) - \int_a^b \varPhi \, dG.$$

Since $\varPhi$ is continuous, by the first mean value theorem for integrals there exists $x \in [a,b]$ such that

$$\int_a^b \varPhi \, dG = \varPhi(x)\int_a^b dG = \varPhi(x)[G(b) - G(a)].$$

Hence,

$$\begin{align}\int_a^bG(t) \varphi(t) \, dt &= G(b)\varPhi(b) - \varPhi(x)[G(b) - G(a)] \\ &= G(a) \varPhi(x) + G(b)[\varPhi(b) - \varPhi(x)] \\ &= G(a) \int_a^x \varphi(t) dt + G(b) \int_x^b \varphi(t) \, dt \end{align}$$

Since we can obtain the same result by replacing $G$ with $\hat{G}$ where $\hat{G}(t) = G(t) $ on $[a,b)$ and $\hat{G}(b) = 0$ we obtain

$$\begin{align}\int_a^bG(t) \varphi(t) \, dt &= \int_a^b\hat{G}(t) \varphi(t) \, dt  \\ &= \hat{G}(a) \int_a^x \varphi(t) dt + \hat{G}(b) \int_x^b \varphi(t) \, dt \\ &= G(a) \int_a^x \varphi(t) dt \end{align} $$

Note that there is no reason why we must restrict $x \in (a,b]$. This would become evident by working through the proof of the first mean value theorem for integrals where no such restriction applies. If $\varPhi$ is continuous, attaining minimum and maximum values at $\xi_1$ and $\xi_2,$ and it happens that $\varPhi(\xi_1) < \varPhi(a) < \varPhi(\xi_2)$ then $\varPhi(a) = \varPhi(x)$ for at least one other point in $(a,b)$. It is possible that this is a point where $\varPhi(x) = \int_a^b \varPhi \, dG / [G(b) - G(a)]$.

Comment: Sorry for adding a comment to this old post. How would you say $$\int_a^bG(t) \varphi(t) \, dt = \int_a^b G \, d\varPhi = G(b)\varPhi(b) - \int_a^b \varPhi \, dG.$$?

Comment: We can’t guarantee that $\varPhi$ is differentiable

Comment: @ylh0501: With $\phi$ merely integrable it is true we can't guarantee that $\Phi$ is differentiable everywhere (although it is a.e. differentiable). Neverthless we can prove $\int_a^bG(t)\phi(t) \, dt = \int_a^bGd\Phi$ without any mention of differentiability.  This is a special case of what I proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2562823/148510) when $g$ in that answer is $g(t) = t$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly more general result that extends the OP statement for Lebesgue integrable functions:

Let $m$ denote the Lebesgue measure on the real line.

> **Proposition:** Suppose $g$ is a monotone right-continuous with left limits function defined on an interval $[a,b]$, and $f\in L_1([a,b],m)$
> There is a point $x_0\in[a, b]$ such that
> \begin{align}\int^b_a f(t)g(t-)\,dt= g(a)\int^{x_0}_af(t)\,dt+g(b)\int^b_{x_0}f(t)\,dt\tag{0}\label{zero}
> \end{align}
>
> - If $g\geq0$ and monotone nondecreasing, then a point $x_0\in[a,b]$ can be chosen so that
>   \begin{align}\int^b_a f(t)g(t-)\,dt= g(b)\int^b_{x_0}f(t)\,dt\tag{1}\label{one}
>   \end{align}
> - If $g\geq0$ and monotone non increasing, then a point $x_0\in[a,b]$ can be chosen so that
>   \begin{align}\int^b_a f(t)g(t-)\,dt= g(a)\int^{x_0}_af(t)\,dt\tag{2}\label{two}
>   \end{align}

***Comment*** The integral $\int^b_af(t)g(t-)\,dt$ can be change to $\int^b_b f(t)g(t)\,dt$ since $g(t)=g(t-)$ $m$-a.s. However, it is convenient to keep the former expression to make the application of Lebesgue integration by parts clearer.

*Proof:* Suppose $g$ is monotone nondecreasing.
Define $F(x)=\int^x_a f(t)\,dt$, $a\leq x\leq b$.

Let $\nu_G$ be the unique Borel measure on $(a,b]$ induced by $g$ (notice that $\nu_g$ is a nonnegative measure and that $\nu_g((x,y])=g(y)-g(x)$ for all $a\leq x\leq y\leq b$).
Notice that $F$ is absolutely continuous. Let $\mu_F$ be the unique signed measure induced by $F$ (which is necessarily of finite variation). Then $\mu_F\ll m$ and $\mu_F=f\mathbb{1}_{[a,b]}\,dm$. An application of [Lebesgue integration by parts](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3724004/121671) yields
\begin{align}
\int^a_b f(t)g(t-)\,dt&=\int_{(a,b]}g(-t) \mu_F(dt)=F(b)g(b)-F(a)g(a)-\int_{(a,b]}F(t)\,\nu_g(dt)\tag{3}\label{three}
\end{align}
If $m=\min_{a\leq t\leq b}F(t)$ and $M=\max_{a\leq t\leq b}F(t)$, then
$$m(g(b)-g(a))\leq \int_{(a,b]}F(t)\,\nu_g(dt)\leq M(g(b)-g(a))$$
If  $g$ is not constant ($g(a)<g(b)$), there is $x_0\in[a,b]$ such that
\begin{align}
F(x_0)(g(b)-g(a))=\int_{(a,b]}F(t)\,\nu_g(dt)\tag{4}\label{four}
\end{align}
If $g$ is constant, any $x_0\in(a, b)$ will do. Substituting \eqref{four} on \eqref{three} yields \eqref{zero}:
\begin{align}
\int^b_a f(t)g(t-)\,dt&= g(a)(F(x_0)-F(a)) + g(b)(F(b)-F(x_0))
\end{align}
\eqref{zero} follows immediately.

**Remark:** if in addition $f$ is not a constant function (a.s.) on $[a,b]$, then the point $x_0$ can be chosen in $(a, b)$.

- To obtained \eqref{one}, extend $g$ as $g(x)=0$ for $x<a$,and $g(x)=g(b)$ is $x>b$. Extend $f$ as $0$ out side $[a,b]$. By part (1), for any $\varepsilon>0$,  there is $x_\varepsilon\in[a-\varepsilon,b]$ such that
  $$\int^b_af(t)g(t-)\,dt=\int^b_{a-\varepsilon}f(t)g(t-)\,dt=g(b)\int^b_{x_\varepsilon}f(t)\,dt$$
  The conclusion follows by letting $\varepsilon\rightarrow0$
- \eqref{two} can be obtained from \eqref{two} by reversing the direction of the integrals, that is $\tilde{f}(t)=f(b+a-t)$ and $\tilde{g}(t)=g(b+a-t)$. Notice that $\tilde{g}$ is monotone nondecreasing whenever $g$ is monotone nonincreasing.